# Rotate Axis for matplotlib Annotate text : python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i am trying to annotate all my data points, but the text while annotating is over lapping with each other,

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(70,2))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.style.use('ggplot')
axess= plt.subplot(1,1,1)
axess.plot_date(idx2,stock2,'--')

axess.set_title("Doc_ID:7377")
axess.set_ylabel('1 - Online, 0 - Offline')

for i,txt in enumerate(date_match_df['service_name_'].tolist()):
    print(txt)
    axess.annotate(txt,(mdates.date2num(idx2[i]),stock2[i]),)
axess.yaxis.grid(True)
axess.xaxis.grid(True)

axess.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator())
axess.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('\n\n%b-%Y'))

axess.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.DayLocator())
axess.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('\n%d-%a'))
plt.tight_layout()

fig.savefig('happynewyear.svg')
```

the graph looks like this: 
[image: graph pic]

**how to rotate the text?**

Comment: Method `.annotate()` has `rotation` parameter with zero default value. Try rotation=90.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Additional arguments to the [`.annotate()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate)-method are passed to [Text](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text), so you can do e.g.:

```
for i,txt in enumerate(date_match_df['service_name_'].tolist()):
    print(txt)
    axess.annotate(txt,(mdates.date2num(idx2[i]),stock2[i]), ha='left', rotation=60)
```

Where the change from your code is the addition of `ha='left', rotation=60` in the end.

Comment: can we have line spacing between text if the there are multiple points on the same date.?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best approach to increase readability of overlapping texts is in your case. I think perhaps the text appears in each annotation box, that you explicit position. What does it look like now? Might be better to create a new question of SO to get more answers to that problem too.